# Need to print only the high priority key in dict, when a values search matches multiple keys ( python)

Tags: python

Need to print only the highest priority KEY, when search is matching multiple dict values.

```
ERROR_CATEGORIES_TO_SEARCH_1 = {
                "VEHICAL_1" : ['CAR'],
                "VEHICAL_2": ['BIKE'],
        "VEHICAL_3"  : ["TRUCK"],
                "VEHICAL_4" : ['AEROPLANE'],
                "VEHICAL_5" : ['SHIP'],
        "VEHICAL_6"   : ['BOAT'],
                "VEHICAL_7" : ['CART'],
                "VEHICAL_8" : ['CYCLE']
            }
  
 
  prio_list = ['VEHICAL_1', 'VEHICAL_2' , 'VEHICAL_3' , 'VEHICAL_4', 'VEHICAL_5', 'VEHICAL_6','VEHICAL_7', 'VEHICAL_8']
 
 
  res = ERROR_CATEGORIES_TO_SEARCH_1.get(prio_list[0], ERROR_CATEGORIES_TO_SEARCH_1.get(prio_list[1], 
                                  ERROR_CATEGORIES_TO_SEARCH_1.get(prio_list[2], ERROR_CATEGORIES_TO_SEARCH_1.get(prio_list[3], ERROR_CATEGORIES_TO_SEARCH_1.get(prio_list[4], ERROR_CATEGORIES_TO_SEARCH_1.get(prio_list[5] , ERROR_CATEGORIES_TO_SEARCH_1.get(prio_list[6], ERROR_CATEGORIES_TO_SEARCH_1.get(prio_list[7]))))))))
```

```
MESSAGE_A  = "I bought a new CAR and a BIKE"
MESSAGE_B  = "WOW That SHIP is so huge and beautiful"
MESSAGE_C  = "only mode to travel through hill station is by TRUCK"
MESSAGE_D  = "First will ride on a CYCLE and then by BOAT"
```

```
resultant_key = [key for (key, lst) in ERROR_CATEGORIES_TO_SEARCH_1.items() for ele in lst if ele in MESSAGE_A]
//OUTPUT:: VEHICAL_1, VEHICAL_2

resultant_key = [key for (key, lst) in ERROR_CATEGORIES_TO_SEARCH_1.items() for ele in lst if ele in MESSAGE_B]
//OUTPUT:: VEHICAL_5

resultant_key = [key for (key, lst) in ERROR_CATEGORIES_TO_SEARCH_1.items() for ele in lst if ele in MESSAGE_c]
//OUTPUT:: VEHICAL_3

resultant_key = [key for (key, lst) in ERROR_CATEGORIES_TO_SEARCH_1.items() for ele in lst if ele in MESSAGE_D]
//OUTPUT :: VEHICAL_6, VEHICAL_8
```

Since i need to print only prioritized KEY's to be printed, **Below is the Expected output::**

```
resultant_key = [key for (key, lst) in ERROR_CATEGORIES_TO_SEARCH_1.items() for ele in lst if ele in MESSAGE_A]
//OUTPUT:: VEHICAL_1


resultant_key = [key for (key, lst) in ERROR_CATEGORIES_TO_SEARCH_1.items() for ele in lst if ele in MESSAGE_D]
//OUTPUT :: VEHICAL_6
```

Any suggestions on this would be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the logic in a function, and use the return statement in a loop, to return only the first (i.e. the highest priority) key.

```py
def find_highest(message):
    for key in prio_list:
        for word in ERROR_CATEGORIES_TO_SEARCH_1.get(key, []):
            if word in message:
                return key
```

```
>>> for message in (MESSAGE_A, MESSAGE_B, MESSAGE_C, MESSAGE_D):
...     print(find_highest(message))
... 
VEHICAL_1
VEHICAL_5
VEHICAL_3
VEHICAL_6
```

Comment: i am new to python, can i get explanation for this please::   for word in ERROR_CATEGORIES_TO_SEARCH_1.get(key, []):

Comment: The second argument for `dict.get(...)` is the default value which will be returned if the key cannot be found (normally: `None`). But with default empty list, the iteration `for word in ...` is simply still working (iteration steps = 0, instead of failing iteration, because you cannot iterate over `None`). It's the same as you used in your huge `res = ...` statement, which you don't need, at all with the changes in this answer, see also https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

Comment: Thanks, this was confusing  :: key, []